# Serve static files from docker containers without webserver, pointed to by nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, frontend, reverse-proxy

Issue, I would like to have a nginx (docker)container which proxies request to multiple other containers containing only frontend static files. First off, is it possible to fetch my frontend(static files) from a docker container without the container containing a webserver like express or nginx which receive the request and serves my files? If, so I planned on letting my nginx container route my request to the frontend containers and serve the files from that singel webserver.

Is this a recommended way to go about serving multiple frontend pages?

Comment: why do you want an idle container(process) just for the sake of storing files? why don't use a volume?

Comment: @Siyu I don't know what is recommended way to do this. Thats why I am asking :)

Comment: @Siyu the idea seems very clear to me. E.g. having one server serving three static presentations. The idea is do it using one nginx (via docker or from the system) and three docker images delivering the static content. Advantage is, that docker image with static content shall be easy to build (on CI/CD server) and to update (on live server).
Anyway, I do not know of easy way to that so far.